# Android app not showing complete Samsung S3 mini

Tags: android, android-studio, apk

I'm new to android and working on my first app which is from a online course project.  The fact is that on Android Studio the app is working fine, but I built the apk file to test it on my phone (Samsung galaxy s3 mini).    On device, the app is not showing complete as it is missing an edit text and a button at the bottom of the layout.   I'm attaching  two screenshots, the first one of the app running on the emulator, and the one running on my smartphone.

App running in the emulator:

[image: App running in the emulator]

App running on the smartphone:

[image: App running on the smartphone]

Layout code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="10dp"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.linfosoft.hangdroid.GameActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_game">

<ImageView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="350dp"
android:id="@+id/imageView"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:src="@drawable/hangdroid_0"
android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

<LinearLayout
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:baselineAligned="false"
android:background="@drawable/gradient_background"
android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:id="@+id/layoutAddLetter"
android:layout_marginTop="90dp">

<TextView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
android:text="Ingresa letra"
android:id="@+id/textView2"
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
android:layout_marginLeft="40dp" />

<EditText
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/editText"
android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
android:maxLength="1" />
<Button
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Revisar"
android:id="@+id/button2"
android:onClick="introduceLetter" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
android:id="@+id/layoutLetters">

</LinearLayout>

<TextView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
android:id="@+id/textView7"
android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
android:textColor="@color/red" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: do you have device specific layouts ?

Comment: Post your layout file.

Comment: Updated the post and included the layout code.

Answer (score 0):

put your xml code within of a ScrolView:

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >


    your xml

</ScrollView>
```

or add weight at your layouts:

```
<LinearLayout
      android:orientation="horizontal"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_weight="1">

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I will try the second one, because i would not like the user having to scroll up and down while playing. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your Hangman picture is really height as it has a value of 350dp

Please check this code:

```
 <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:paddingBottom="10dp"
 app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
 tools:context="com.linfosoft.hangdroid.GameActivity"
 tools:showIn="@layout/activity_game">

 <RelativeLayout
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="350dp"
 android:id="@+id/imageView"
 android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
 android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
 android:src="@drawable/hangdroid_0"
 android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

<LinearLayout
 android:orientation="horizontal"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:baselineAligned="false"
 android:background="@drawable/gradient_background"
 android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
 android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
 android:id="@+id/layoutAddLetter"
 android:layout_marginTop="90dp">

 <TextView
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
 android:text="Ingresa letra"
 android:id="@+id/textView2"
 android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
 android:layout_marginLeft="40dp" />

 <EditText
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:id="@+id/editText"
 android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
 android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
 android:maxLength="1" />
 <Button
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:text="Revisar"
 android:id="@+id/button2"
 android:onClick="introduceLetter" />
 </LinearLayout>

 <LinearLayout
 android:orientation="horizontal"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
 android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
 android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
 android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
 android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
 android:id="@+id/layoutLetters">

 </LinearLayout>

 <TextView
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
 android:id="@+id/textView7"
 android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
 android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
 android:textColor="@color/red" />

 </RelativeLayout>
 <ScrollView>
```

As you see I used `ScrollView`, but scrolling a view would be enabled ONLY if a device would not have enough space to take everything on its screen.

In the other case it would be like any other static layout.

It doesn't mean that you would scroll it on every device or your game would be less attractive ;-)

**Also** you can change height of your picture to `wrap_content`, bu I suppose that author if this tutorial make this height by value, because the picture in the reality is much bigger than that with height of `350dp`.

Comment: thaks. I'll do this.